# how to create a text box with mask value like this PAN-123-1234-12345 in kendo

Tags: javascript, typescript, kendo-ui, maskedtextbox

I want a text box with default value PAN---.

I can enter like this PAN-123-1234-12345

first 3 should be character
next 3 should be integer
next 4 should be integer
next 5 should be integer

i tried below code

```
 <kendo-label [text]="'PAN Number'">
      <kendo-maskedtextbox          
     
      [mask]="'PAN-000-0000-00000'"
      >
    </kendo-maskedtextbox>
```

getting output

```
_A_-___-____-_____
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mask should be one of these 3 depending on what you allow for first 3 characters:

```
"LLL-000-0000-00000" //first 3 have to be letters
"AAA-000-0000-00000" //first 3 have to be alphanumeric
"&&&-000-0000-00000" //first 3 can be any character
```

Then set value to 'PAN' to default the first 3 letters.

e.g.

```
$("#maskedtextbox").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "LLL-000-0000-00000",
    value: 'PAN'
});
```

[DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OHasEfiH)